# Unable to create multiple files using foreachBatch in spark (This Code Works Now)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I want to save files to multiple destination using `foreachBatch` , the code is running fine but `foreachBatch` isn't running the way wanted.
Kindly help me with this if you got any clue.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

object multiDestination {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("Writing data to multiple destinations")
    .getOrCreate()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val mySchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("Id", IntegerType),
      StructField("Name", StringType)
    ))

    val askDF = spark
      .readStream
      .format("csv")
     .option("header","true")
      .schema(mySchema)
      .load("/home/amulya/Desktop/csv/")
//println(askDF.show())
  println(askDF.isStreaming)

      askDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (askDF : DataFrame , batchId:Long) =>
          askDF.persist()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO. *foreachBatch isn't running the way wanted* : would you please show error logs?

Comment: Hi, There is no error else it would have been easier to dealt with. I can tell you that the complier isn't compiling the foreachBatch part of the code

Comment: So, compiler errors are welcome. Just because we need to at least have a chance to understand what on earth you are trying to ask.

Comment: @Yasen I've updated everything with the error

Comment: Error message said that your pathes to save should be a directory not a file

Comment: Just solved that , appreciate the help